# How do props work when used by a component declared inside another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I am making a multi-stage form in react. The overall component dependency structure is as follows:

- MainForm

  - SubForm1
  - SubForm2
  - SubForm3

The `MainForm` component has two states called `step` and `formData`, and methods called handleNext, handleBack which modify the state `step`. It also has a method called handleChange, which reads the value from input fields present in `SubForm*` and update the state `formData`, so that on clicking back and next the formData stays there until a final API call has been made on the last `SubForm3`. Upon which the MainForm component is unmounted. The MainForm uses switch case to render a particular SubForm using the state `step` as the decision variable.

I am passing the following to SubForms as props:

- formData
- handleNext
- handlePrev
- handleChange

In SubForm1 I have the following piece of code:

```
import React from 'react';
const SubForm1 = ({
    formData,
    handleNext,
    handlePrev,
    handleChange,
}) => {
    const FormInput = ({ attr }) => <input name={attr} onChange={handleChange} value={formData[attr]} />;

    return (
        <FormContainer>
            <form>
                  <input name='fullName' onChange={handleChange} value={field_values.fullName} />
                  <FormInput attr="employee_id" />
            </form>
            <button onClick={prevStep}>Back</Button>
            <button onClick={nextStep}>Next</button>
        </FormContainer>
      );
}
```

The handleChange method captures the user input via the onChange event and upadates the corresponding field. It is declared in MainForm.jsx as:

```
// MainForm.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MainForm = () => {

    const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ fullName: '', employee_id: '' });

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.persist();
        setFormData(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        }));
    };

    const handleNext = () => {
        setStep(old => (old + 1));
    };

    const handleBack = () => {
        setStep(old => (old - 1));
    };
```

It works smoothly in the input field (fullName) - The value updates as the user types and the formData state remains intact on traversing through subforms.

But for the `employee_id` input, following happens:

1. A character is entered in the employee_id input field.
2. The employee_id input field immediately looses focus.
3. The user has to click on the employee_id input field again to gain focus (of course without which he/she cannot type into the field)
4. Go To step 1.

The state formData is however updated since on going to next/previous SubForm, the state formData remains intact.

I feel that it has something to do with how I have declared the `FormInput` component. I am not passing handleChange as a prop to it from SubForm1, but instead relying on the scope.

After googling a lot, I couldn't get an answer for my question, since search engines confused my question with answers relating to Component composition on any query containing 'declaring a component inside another component` etc.

PS. I am relatively new to react and javascript, so please feel free to suggest any better ways to implement the above.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should change something with "value" in FormInput. What do you have in formData[attr]?

Comment: formData is a state object = { fullName: '', employee_id: '' };
the handleChange method is actually doing that.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes `event.persist();` is causing problem.
If you want your `event.target.name` and `event.target.value` then just create two variables which will store these values. 
and remove `event.persist()`.

just try with below code :

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // event.persist(); //comment out this line
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;

    setFormData(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value,
    }));
};
```

Comment: Hey, tried out what you suggested. But it doesn't work, I feel the bug is in declaring the FormInput component inside the subForm component. May be, because subForm* use formData state and onchange of formData, ReactDOM rerenders the subForm component, which causes the functional component FormInput to be redeclared, which inturn causes the FormInput field to be replaced with a new FormInput instance. I really don't know if it is so.